# ADO.Net - How to insert data in table without knowing the schema

Tags: ado.net

I have scenario where i need to insert some data into a oracle table using data tables and adapters of the ADO.Net. The schema of the table is not known. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked here - [Retrieving Database Schema Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcax58fh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?
You can use the *GetSchema* method to help you programmatically examine your database's schema. The method returns a *DataTable* of schema information. (although the OracleClient is technically deprecated now).

```
string myConnection = @<fill in your connectionstring here>

using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(myConnection))
{
   connection.Open();

   DataTable schemaTable = connection.GetSchema("Tables");

   foreach(DataRow row in schemaTable.Rows)
      Console.WriteLine(row["TABLE_NAME"];
} // end using OracleConnection
```

Will get you all the available tables in the database pointed at by your ConnectionString. If you read up on the linked info about you'll find that you can walk into your whole database using this one *very useful* method.
Hope that sets you on your way!